# Python for loop skips over '>' symbol fasta format

Tags: python, for-loop, fasta

I'm given an original dna sequence in fasta format, and then several dna sequences which represent introns. I'm trying to distinguish the original sequence and then store the introns in a list.

This first part just tries to store the original dna sequence in a string.

```
data = """>Rosalind_10
ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG
>Rosalind_12 
ATCGGTCGAA
>Rosalind_15
ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT"""

data = data.split()
original = ""
print(data)
data.pop(0)
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x])
    if data[x][0] == '>':
        data.pop(x)
        break
    else:
        original += data.pop(x)
```

The `print(data)` returns

```
['>Rosalind_10', 'ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG',     '>Rosalind_12', 'ATCGGTCGAA', '>Rosalind_15', 'ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT']
```

as expected, but the subsequent `print(data[x])` line returns

```
ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG

ATCGGTCGAA

ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT
```

And then it throws an IndexError. It seems to me that the for loop is somehow skipping the items in the data list which contain the '>' symbol which is why the if statement doesn't cause a break to happen and it prints all the items when it should only print the original sequence and the very next line with '>' and then the for loop should break. I'm wondering if someone can explain why the for loop ignores items in the data list which have the '>' symbol. Thanks

Comment: Is the desired output to have a string of all the sequences that don't start with a '>'?

Comment: I want to store the first sequence rosalind10 as the string original, and then I want to store the subsequent sequences as a list of strings (introns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that you're both getting the `IndexError` and the lines with `>` are not causing a break is that you're modifying `data` while iterating through it with the `pop()` calls. Another way to iterate through `data` is to just do it directly:

```
# ...
data = data.split()
data.pop(0) # remove Rosalind_10
original = data.pop(0) # store sequence for Rosalind_10
introns = []
for piece in data:
    if piece.startswith('>'):
        continue
    else:
        introns.append(piece)
print('original', original)
print('introns', introns)
```

This prints:

```
original ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG
introns ['ATCGGTCGAA', 'ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT']
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I didn't notice that I was modifying it while iterating! Makes much more sense now

Comment: Perhaps `piece.startswith('>')` might be more clear than `piece[0] == '>'`?  At the very least it might be more idiomatic python.